# shopify xml request from GAE python

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make requests to the shopify.com API over GAE python
the url i have to request is not formed in the usual format.

it is composed like **http://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.xml**

with urllib I can request it but i cant set the headers for an xml request so it doesn't work.

urllib2, httplib... are having problems with the ':'.

I get either a 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known' or a 'nonnumeric port' because it expects a port number after the semicolon.

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [how to do HTTP Basic authentication](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml) in Python.  See especially the section on [Doing it Properly](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml#doing-it-properly).

Comment: thank you but the problem here is that i have to access this exact url to access the API. the problem here is the colon.

Comment: The x:y@ isn't part of the hostname; it's just a way of doing the HTTP Basic authentication right in the URL instead of Doing It Properly.